# unable to authenticate sonarqube using LDAP

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I configured sonarqube 5.6 using LDAP 2.0 plugin. The issue is user is unable to connect sonarqube using LDAP credentials. But unfortunately, sometimes it get connected after throwing up this error in log
`Error from external users provider: exception Java::OrgSonarApiUtils::SonarException: Unable to retrieve details for user XXXX in <default>
2017.05.04 11:39:26 ERROR web[rails] Error from external groups provider: Unable to retrieve groups for user XXXX in <default>` After throwing up this error, LDAP is working fine.But when I install sonarqube again from scratch it disables user to login till I get same error.

This is my LDAP configuration

```
sonar.security.realm=LDAP
ldap.url=ldap://ldap-google.com
ldap.bindDn=CN=x12345,OU=Corp,OU=GOOGLE,OU=Admin Accounts,DC=ggle,DC=com
ldap.bindPassword=password

# User Configuration    
ldap.user.baseDn=DC=ggle,DC=com
ldap.user.request=(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={login}))
ldap.user.realNameAttribute=cn
ldap.user.emailAttribute=mail

# Group Configuration
ldap.group.baseDn=CN=x12345,OU=corpoxxxx,DC=ggle,DC=com
ldap.group.request=(&(objectClass=group)(member={dn}))
ldap.group.idAttribute=sAMAccountName
```

when I tried to trace the log file I got some inputs as

```
DEBUG web[o.s.p.l.LdapUsersProvider] null
javax.naming.PartialResultException: null
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.hasMoreImpl(AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.java:237) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.hasMore(AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.java:189) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at org.sonar.plugins.ldap.LdapSearch.findUnique(LdapSearch.java:146) ~[na:na]
```

and also

```
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException:DomainDnsZones.ggle.com:389
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapReferralContext.<init>(LdapReferralContext.java:95) ~[na:1.8.0_101] at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapReferralException.getReferralContext(LdapReferralException.java:150) ~[na:1.8.0_101] at com.sun.jndi.ldap.AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.hasMoreReferrals(AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.java:325) ~[na:1.8.0_101] at com.sun.jndi.ldap.AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.hasMoreImpl(AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.java:227) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    ... 399 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
```

Comment: See if [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/sonarqube/referral%7Csort:date/sonarqube/0zK6_oxf-VY/jZOpuYvxBgAJ) on a similar error helps (notably latest exchanges).

Comment: Sure I will have a look @NicolasB.-SonarSourceTeam

Comment: It didn't helped me @NicolasB.

Comment: any news here? im also having the same problem